# Error during install of player node module with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, audio-player

I would to play some music on my nodejs script. I try to install [player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/player) module with npm.

But when I launch the install,they return this :

```
speaker@0.2.1 install /home/tr*****/Documents/Programation/Node.js/node_modules/player/node_modules/speaker
> node-gyp rebuild

make: entrant dans le répertoire « /home/tr*****/Documents/Programation/Node.js/node_modules/player/node_modules/speaker/build »
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/output/deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.o
../deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.c:19:28: fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/output/deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.o] Erreur 1
make: quittant le répertoire « /home/tr*****/Documents/Programation/Node.js/node_modules/player/node_modules/speaker/build »
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/tr*****/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-49-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/tr*****/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/tr*****/Documents/Programation/Node.js/node_modules/player/node_modules/speaker
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 

> lame@1.1.1 install /home/tr*****/Documents/Programation/Node.js/node_modules/player/node_modules/lame
> node-gyp rebuild

make: entrant dans le répertoire « /home/tr*****/Documents/Programation/Node.js/node_modules/player/node_modules/lame/build »
deps/mpg123/test.target.mk:117: attention : écrasement des commandes pour la cible « Release/test »
deps/lame/test.target.mk:125: attention : anciennes commandes ignorées pour la cible « Release/test »
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/VbrTag.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/bitstream.o
../deps/lame/libmp3lame/bitstream.c: In function ‘do_gain_analysis’:
../deps/lame/libmp3lame/bitstream.c:992:24: warning: unused variable ‘rov’ [-Wunused-variable]
     RpgResult_t *const rov = &gfc->ov_rpg;
                        ^
../deps/lame/libmp3lame/bitstream.c:991:32: warning: unused variable ‘rsv’ [-Wunused-variable]
     RpgStateVar_t const *const rsv = &gfc->sv_rpg;
                                ^
../deps/lame/libmp3lame/bitstream.c:990:34: warning: unused variable ‘cfg’ [-Wunused-variable]
     SessionConfig_t const *const cfg = &gfc->cfg;
                                  ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/encoder.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/fft.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/gain_analysis.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/id3tag.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/lame.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/newmdct.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/presets.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/psymodel.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/quantize.o
../deps/lame/libmp3lame/quantize.c: In function ‘VBR_new_iteration_loop’:
../deps/lame/libmp3lame/quantize.c:1734:28: warning: variable ‘fullframebits’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         int     mean_bits, fullframebits;
                            ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/quantize_pvt.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/reservoir.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/set_get.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/tables.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/takehiro.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/util.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/vbrquantize.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mp3lame/deps/lame/libmp3lame/version.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/lame/libmp3lame.a
  COPY Release/libmp3lame.a
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/compat.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/parse.o
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/parse.c: In function ‘handle_id3v2’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/parse.c:1013:31: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘else’ statement [-Wempty-body]
  else debug("no useful ID3v2");
                               ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/parse.c: In function ‘skip_junk’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/parse.c:1081:71: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘else’ statement [-Wempty-body]
  else debug1("hopefully found one at %"OFF_P, (off_p)fr->rd->tell(fr));
                                                                       ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/parse.c: In function ‘wetwork’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/parse.c:1149:114: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘if’ statement [-Wempty-body]
    if(VERBOSE3) debug3("resync try %li at %"OFF_P", got newhead 0x%08lx", try, (off_p)fr->rd->tell(fr),  newhead);
                                                                                                                  ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/frame.o
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/frame.c: In function ‘INT123_frame_outbuffer’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/frame.c:184:4: warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 5 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat=]
    if(NOQUIET) error2("have external buffer of size %"SIZE_P", need %"SIZE_P, (size_p)fr->buffer.size, size);
    ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/frame.c: In function ‘INT123_frame_buffers’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/frame.c:285:28: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  if(2*2*0x110*sizeof(real) > buffssize)
                            ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/format.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/dct64.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/equalizer.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/id3.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/optimize.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.o
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c: In function ‘plain_read’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c:60:70: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘if’ statement [-Wempty-body]
  if(VERBOSE3) debug2("read %li bytes of %li", (long)ret, (long)count);
                                                                      ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c: In function ‘bc_add’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c:630:93: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘if’ statement [-Wempty-body]
  if(size >=4) debug4("first bytes: %02x %02x %02x %02x", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
                                                                                             ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c: In function ‘bc_forget’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c:728:42: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘else’ statement [-Wempty-body]
  else debug("forget with nothing there!");
                                          ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c: In function ‘INT123_feed_more’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c:763:33: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘if’ statement [-Wempty-body]
  if(VERBOSE3) debug("feed_more");
                                 ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c:772:82: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘if’ statement [-Wempty-body]
   (unsigned long)fr->rdat.buffer.last->size, (unsigned long)fr->rdat.buffer.size);
                                                                                  ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c: In function ‘buffered_fullread’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c:848:97: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘if’ statement [-Wempty-body]
    if(VERBOSE3) debug1("buffered_fullread: buffering %li bytes from stream (if > 0)", (long)got);
                                                                                                 ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c:856:11: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
    if(got < sizeof(readbuf)) /* That naturally catches got == 0, too. */
           ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/readers.c:867:73: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘if’ statement [-Wempty-body]
  if(VERBOSE3) debug2("wanted %li, got %li", (long)count, (long)gotcount);
                                                                         ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/tabinit.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/libmpg123.o
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/libmpg123.c: In function ‘mpg123_plain_strerror’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/libmpg123.c:1581:29: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  if(errcode >= 0 && errcode < sizeof(mpg123_error)/sizeof(char*))
                             ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/index.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/stringbuf.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/icy.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/icy2utf8.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/ntom.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/synth.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/synth_8bit.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer1.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer2.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.o
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c: In function ‘III_dequantize_sample’:
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:695:12: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  while(num < BITSHIFT) { \
            ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:804:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘REFRESH_MASK’
      REFRESH_MASK;
      ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:695:12: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  while(num < BITSHIFT) { \
            ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:818:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘REFRESH_MASK’
      REFRESH_MASK;
      ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:695:12: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  while(num < BITSHIFT) { \
            ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:842:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘REFRESH_MASK’
      REFRESH_MASK;
      ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:695:12: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  while(num < BITSHIFT) { \
            ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:890:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘REFRESH_MASK’
    REFRESH_MASK;
    ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:695:12: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  while(num < BITSHIFT) { \
            ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:1021:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘REFRESH_MASK’
      REFRESH_MASK;
      ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:695:12: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  while(num < BITSHIFT) { \
            ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:1036:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘REFRESH_MASK’
      REFRESH_MASK;
      ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:695:12: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  while(num < BITSHIFT) { \
            ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:1059:6: note: in expansion of macro ‘REFRESH_MASK’
      REFRESH_MASK;
      ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:695:12: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
  while(num < BITSHIFT) { \
            ^
../deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/layer3.c:1088:4: note: in expansion of macro ‘REFRESH_MASK’
    REFRESH_MASK;
    ^
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/feature.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/synth_s32.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/synth_real.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/mpg123/deps/mpg123/src/libmpg123/dct64_i386.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/mpg123/libmpg123.a
  COPY Release/libmpg123.a
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/lamevectorroutines/deps/lame/libmp3lame/vector/xmm_quantize_sub.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/lame/liblamevectorroutines.a
  COPY Release/liblamevectorroutines.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bindings/src/bindings.o
In file included from ../src/bindings.cc:17:0:
/home/tr*****/.node-gyp/0.12.2/deps/v8/include/v8.h: In function ‘void nodelame::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)’:
/home/tr*****/.node-gyp/0.12.2/deps/v8/include/v8.h:816:13: error: ‘v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()’ is protected
   V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
             ^
../src/bindings.cc:29:15: error: within this context
   HandleScope scope;
               ^
make: *** [Release/obj.target/bindings/src/bindings.o] Erreur 1
make: quittant le répertoire « /home/tr*****/Documents/Programation/Node.js/node_modules/player/node_modules/lame/build »
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/tr*****/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-49-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/tr*****/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/tr*****/Documents/Programation/Node.js/node_modules/player/node_modules/lame
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-49-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/home/tr*****/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/bin/npm" "install" "player"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.8.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! speaker@0.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the speaker@0.2.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the speaker package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls speaker
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Can you help me or do you know an other module to play music
thanks

Sorry for the error i'm french

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the same module and I'm french too (maybe this is the bug XD). Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed `libasound2-dev` before the npm install? On Debian/Ubuntu it seems to be necessary and that's why your installation is missing alsa/asoundlib.h header.

Run `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev` on your terminal and then try to install player again.

Source: https://github.com/turingou/player/issues/35#issuecomment-84525573

Comment: It seems to not be the good solution the error is the same after libasound2-dev install